# Exact distribution of MLE exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

> Let $y_1, \dots,y_n$ be i.i.d. random variables from $Exp(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is scale parameter. I've found the MLE $$\hat \theta=\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_i}{n}$$

Now I need to find the exact distribution of $\hat \theta$.

I know that if $y\sim Exp(\theta)$ than $\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_i\sim Ga(n,\theta)$, so I would say $\hat \theta\sim Ga(n,n\theta)$. Is that correct?

**Edit**

The right solution is $\hat \theta\sim Ga(n,\frac{\theta}{n})$.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $1/\bar{X}_n$?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all :-)

Comment: What is stopping you to check your answer? (Edited the tags to more relevant ones.)

Comment: @Did I'll try to restart from the beginning. Let be $T=\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_i$. Now, if $T\sim Ga(k,\theta)$ then, for any $c \gt 0$, $cT\sim Ga(k,c\theta)$. So, I should correct my answer with $\hat \theta\sim Ga(n,\frac{\theta}{n})$.

Comment: Thus, question solved?

Comment: @Did Yes, solved, I edited with right solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If $X\sim\mathcal{E}xp(\theta)$ where $f_X(x)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$, then $\hat{\theta}=1/\bar{Y}_n$. As such $\sum Y_i \sim Gam(n, \theta)$, then $1/\sum Y_i \sim \text{Inv-Gam}(n, 1/\theta)$. So, your MLE is $n$ times Inverse-Gamma random variable. You can derive its analytical expression by using $f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))|(g^{-1}(y))'|$.

2) If $X\sim\mathcal{E}xp(\theta)$ where $f_X(x)=1/\theta e^{-x/\theta }$, then your answer is correct.

Comment: Hi, I think the MLE is correct because I used scale parameterization of exponential distribution.

Comment: OK, then the answer in the comment seems to be correct...